# How to set mail body as html in curl?

Tags: c++, http, curl

I need to send html table as email body. I just did the below to mention content type as html, but it did not work.

```
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: text/html");
/* pass our list of custom made headers */
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

I couldn't find an example from the library site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` will not work with any of the SMTP options (`CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM`, `CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT`, `CURLOPT_MAIL_AUTH`).  Instead you need to use `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION`.

```
/* Disclaimer: untested code */
char *msg = "To: bob@example.com\r\n"
            "From: alice@example.com\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\n"
            "Mime-version: 1.0\r\n"
            "\r\n"
            "<html><head>\r\n"
            "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii\">\r\n"
            "</head><body>\r\n"
            "<p>Hi Bob</p>\r\n"
            "</body></html>\r\n"

size_t callback(char *buffer, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *instream) {
    /* you actually need to check that buffer <= size * nitems */
    strcat(buffer, msg);
    return strlen(buffer);
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, callback);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

The [documentation for `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html) has more info.  Although, if you're already sending plain text emails, you have been there.

The only real **"trick"** here that is not presented in [Sending Mail Through Curl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html) linked by sameerkn is that you simply dump the `Content-Type` header inside the email buffer.  There is no clever header setting like with HTTP.

---

Also: i'm not sure whether you need a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header, i've set the `charset` above to `us-ascii` but things like `utf-8` might need transfer encoding.

Comment: Thanks grochmal, this one really helped.

Answer (score 1):

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);`  will set the **HTTP  Protocol Header** in your request.

The header which you are showing applies to **E-Mail Data (Header section)**.

E-Mail Data Format: (It has 2 sections, Header and Body separated by blank line)

```
Header: value
Header: value
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
//**********************//  << this is a blank line between Header and Body
Body Of Mail
```

Does your email contains only HTML?

Try adding following header to **Email Headers** as well: `Content-Transfer-Encoding`

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

`quoted-printable` is an encoding done to your HTML data. You can encode data as `base64` as well.

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

**EDIT:  If you are trying to send mail using curl then please refer
[Send Mail Through CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html)

Comment: This did not work for me. I have tried headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64;");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\";");

        /* pass our list of custom made headers */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

Comment: Are you trying to Send Mail Through CURL?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the help. I did that by myself with your header option provided as above.